# Rake, Rspec and Windows

Tags: windows, ruby

If I try and run the simplest of rake rspec tests in my windows environment (which I have basically no experience in) I get the following error:

```
>ruby "D:\Ruby191\bin\rake" test
"D:/Ruby191/bin/ruby.exe" -S bundle exec rspec -cfs spec/app_spec.rb
ruby.exe: invalid switch in RUBYOPT: -F (RuntimeError)
rake aborted!
ruby -S bundle exec rspec -cfs spec/app_spec.rb failed

Tasks: TOP => test => spec
```

I seems that ruby doesn't like that middle `F` flag, but I didn't add it and I can't find any part of the .bat or ruby files which introduces flags.

I've had no luck googling this issue (I may be searching for the wrong terms), does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Can't answer my own question yet: I went and installed Ruby to a folder with spaces in it (Program <b>F</b>iles). *Don't do this*.

Answer (score 2):

I went and installed Ruby to a folder with spaces in it (Program **F**iles). *Don't do this*.

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed Ruby on Windows I assume you used the [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/). Try also installing the [DevKit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/).

I recommend installing to `C:\Ruby`, and running `gem update --system` then `gem update` to make sure everything is up-to-date.